# What is the intended way to match an interior mutable enum?

Tags: enums, rust, matching, interior-mutability

These are the ways I could come up with to try matching a reference counted, interior mutable enum:

```
#![allow(unused)]

use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
struct Bar {
    some_bar: Vec<f64>,
}
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
struct Baz {
    some_baz: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
enum Foo {
    Bar(Bar),
    Baz(Baz),
}

fn is_baz(foo_ref: Rc<RefCell<Foo>>) -> bool {
    match foo_ref {
        Foo::Bar(_) => false,
        Foo::Baz(_) => true,
    }
}

fn is_baz_borrow(foo_ref: Rc<RefCell<Foo>>) -> bool {
    match foo_ref.borrow() {
        Foo::Bar(_) => false,
        Foo::Baz(_) => true,
    }
}

fn is_baz_deref(foo_ref: Rc<RefCell<Foo>>) -> bool {
    match *foo_ref {
        Foo::Bar(_) => false,
        Foo::Baz(_) => true,
    }
}

fn is_baz_get_mut(foo_ref: Rc<RefCell<Foo>>) -> bool {
    match foo_ref.get_mut() {
        Foo::Bar(_) => false,
        Foo::Baz(_) => true,
    }
}

fn is_baz_as_ref(foo_ref: Rc<RefCell<Foo>>) -> bool {
    match foo_ref.as_ref() {
        Foo::Bar(_) => false,
        Foo::Baz(_) => true,
    }
}

fn is_baz_as_ref_borrow(foo_ref: Rc<RefCell<Foo>>) -> bool {
    match foo_ref.as_ref().borrow() {
        Foo::Bar(_) => false,
        Foo::Baz(_) => true,
    }
}

fn is_baz_get_mut_mut(mut foo_ref: Rc<RefCell<Foo>>) -> bool {
    match foo_ref.get_mut() {
        Foo::Bar(_) => false,
        Foo::Baz(_) => true,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::Bar(Bar {
        some_bar: vec![1.1, 999.0],
    });
    let foo_ref = Rc::new(RefCell::new(foo));

    // none of these work
    assert!(is_baz(foo_ref.clone()));
    assert!(is_baz_borrow(foo_ref.clone()));
    assert!(is_baz_deref(foo_ref.clone()));
    assert!(is_baz_get_mut(foo_ref.clone()));
    assert!(is_baz_as_ref(foo_ref.clone()));
    assert!(is_baz_as_ref_borrow(foo_ref.clone()));

    // this works
    assert!(is_baz_get_mut_mut(foo_ref.clone()));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a76f1425c0c551f1daa70b408f955222)

However most ways create an mismatched types error like

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:24:9
   |
24 |         Foo::Baz(_) => true
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::rc::Rc`, found enum `Foo`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<Foo>>`
              found type `Foo`
```

or

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:30:9
   |
30 |         Foo::Bar(_) => false,
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::cell::Ref`, found enum `Foo`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::cell::Ref<'_, Foo, >`
              found type `Foo`
```

The only way that worked is this:

```rust
match foo_ref.get_mut() {
    Foo::Bar(_) => false,
    Foo::Baz(_) => true
}
```

Is this the intended way? Even for read only access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Deref` impl of `Ref`:

```
fn is_baz_get(foo_ref: Rc<RefCell<Foo>>) -> bool {
    match *foo_ref.borrow() {
        Foo::Bar(_) => false,
        Foo::Baz(_) => true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was driving me crazy!

I can even read the contents of the enum if I use ref

```rust

fn is_baz_of_5_deref_borrow(foo_ref: Rc<RefCell<Foo>>) -> bool {
    match *foo_ref.borrow() {
        Foo::Bar(_) => false,
        Foo::Baz(ref baz) => baz ==&Baz{some_baz:5}
    }
}


```